# What is the Polymer 0.5 Core-Scaffolding "Paper" equivalent in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, material-design, polymer-1.0, core-elements, polymer-starter-kit

I'm attempting to create a page that looks like this, where the paper panel overlaps the main header section, then scrolls off the page as the user scrolls:

[image]

Polymer 0.5 supports pages like this with a `<core-header-panel mode="cover">`.

I don't see anything like this in Polymer 1.0, and I can't figure out how to recreate this effect.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`core-header-panel` has been renamed as `paper-header-panel` and it still has a `cover` mode. [Source](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-header-panel)

Comment: Still fighting with this code. The example that they give doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm guessing it's something in my CSS though.

Comment: Didn't import paper-header-panel.html. Thought I did, but it was paper-SCROLL-header-panel.html.

Different files. Ugh.